# Baixar imagens com JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Bom, eu estou precisando que um `script` faça download automático de imagens para mim.

Por exemplo a `url` da imagem começa em [http://*/the_gamer/the_gamer035-01.jpg*](http://*/the_gamer/the_gamer035-01.jpg) até [http:///the_gamer/the_gamer035-25.jpg](http://*/the_gamer/the_gamer035-25.jpg), assim preciso de um `script` que vá baixando todas as imagens, se for possível preciso que o nome da foto seja mantido como o original.

Comment: legal, o que vc já tentou fazer, já tem algum código, algum teste?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311645/download-image-with-javascript

Comment: Bom, eu não achei nenhuma função nativa do javascript para download.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz não existe um código que faça isso diretamente, mas veja a resposta do Luiz Santos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possível solução seria criar uma tag  e ir pegando as imagens através delas.

```
// Função para baixar a imagem...
function downloadImage(src) {
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = src;

    return img;
}

// Imagens baixadas:
var images = [];

// Loop para baixar as imagens...
for(var i = 1; i < 35; i++) {
    // Primeiro pegamos o valor de "i" e transformamos em uma string...
    var n = i.toString();

    // Colocar um zero a mais caso seja necessário...
    if(n.length < 2) {
        n = "0" + n;
    }

    // Agora é só criar uma tag <img> e ir colocando na Array...
    images.push(downloadImage("http:///the_gamer/the_gamer035-" + n + ".jpg"));
}
```

Depois seria só ir pegando o que foi guardado na Array.

Answer (score 3):

Aproveitando a idéia do loop do Luiz Santos e o script do brother [**deste post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311645/download-image-with-javascript)

```
for(var x = 1;x <= 25; x++ ){
if( x < 10)
var url = "0" + x + ".jpg";
else
var url = x + ".jpg";

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "http:///the_gamer/the_gamer035-"+url;
a.download = "035-"+url;
a.click();

}
```

No Google Chrome Versão 61.0.3163.100 é feita uma pergunta "Fazer o download de vários arquivos" "Permitir" "Bloquear". O navegador deve estar configurado para baixar arquivos automaticamente. Caso contrario ficará aguardando a confirmação de cada download.

Para configurar downloads automaticamente no `Google Chrome`

1 - No computador, abra o Google Chrome.

2 - No canto superior direito, clique em [image: tres] [image: seta] Configurações

3 - Na parte inferior da página, clique em Avançado

4 - Na seção "Downloads", ajuste suas configurações de download

> O link da pergunta parece não funcionar `http:///the_gamer/the_gamer035-01.jpg`

Comment: http://uploader.centraldemangas.com.br/the_gamer/the_gamer035-01.jpg

Comment: Testei mas não baixa a fotografia e sim uma pagina html. LOL

Comment: acho que vc errou no URL Esse seu link abre uma pagina, não é um URL de imagens

Comment: Quando carrego a URL que mandei agora no navegador aparece a imagem. Mas quando ponho no script só baixa a pagina principal do site. A URL é "http://uploader.centraldemangas.com.br/the_gamer/the_gamer035-01.jpg"

Comment: boa @LeoCaracciolo curti a ideia.

Comment: esse seu link redireciona para http://centraldemangas.etc.br/

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz  fiz uma pagina temporaria para vc testar  http://kithomepage.com/sos/download-img-com-javascript.htm

Comment: Funcionou, eu já tinha testado em outa pagina e tinha funcionado perfeitamente, só nessa que mandei acima que não funfa. Mas VLW.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz  pois então, a galera desse site implementou algo para não funfar e te deixar a ver navios :)

Comment: Putz, malditos kkk. Vlw ai mano.

Comment: Performance muito ruim quando usado base64 de tamanho maior que 1MB no src da imagem.

Answer (score 2):

O Javascript para baixa uma imagem é o seguinte:

```
var a = $("<a>")
    .attr("href", "http:///the_gamer/the_gamer035-01.jpg")
    .attr("download", "img.png")
    .appendTo("body");

a[0].click();

a.remove();
```

Sabendo disso basta fazer um for percorrendo o numero de item que deseja:

```
var url = "http:///the_gamer/the_gamer035-"

for(var x = 1;x <= 25; x++ ){
if( x < 10)
var url = url + "0" + x + ".jpg";
else
var url = url + x + ".jpg";

var a = $("<a>")
    .attr("href", "http:///the_gamer/the_gamer035-01.jpg")
    .attr("download", "img.png")
    .appendTo("body");

a[0].click();

a.remove();
}
```

Ele baixara todas as imagens ate o numero de x estipulado para saída do for.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Conforme dito pelo Renan nos comentarios:

> Vale lembrar que para funcionar de um jeito confortável o navegador
>   deve estar configurado para baixar arquivos automaticamente. Caso
>   contrário ele aguardará pela confirmação do usuário sobre onde salvar
>   cada arquivo

Comment: Boa ideia. Vale lembrar que para funcionar de um jeito confortável o navegador deve estar configurado para baixar arquivos automaticamente. Caso contrário ele aguardará pela confirmação do usuário sobre onde salvar cada arquivo.

Comment: Verdade! vou somar na resposta esta observação

Comment: Testei mas não baixa a fotografia e sim uma pagina html. LOL

Comment: http://uploader.centraldemangas.com.br/the_gamer/the_gamer035-01.jpg

Comment: Não é porque sem link de imagem não premite o acesso direto? ou algo do tipo, porque ao acessar o link que você cedeu sou direcionado para o site não para a imagem.

Comment: Ai eu não sei, pode ser isso?

Comment: acredito que sim